# Haskell indentation error?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

[image: Indentation problem]

I attached the code, with indentation, anyone know where is the problem?

Error code:

```
zo.hs:7:9: parse error (possibly incorrect indentation)
```

Comment: You know, this would be *much* easier if you actually copied and pasted your code here instead of using a screenshot.

Comment: the printscreen just for indentation

Comment: The "parse error" is the interesting part of the error message, indentation is just meant as a helpful reminder. Most of the time it has nothing to do with the error itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line

```
[...] = show x ++   ++ show [...]
```

contains several syntax errors. In particular, `(++)` is a binary operator, not something to surround your `show foo` with.

Try

```
[...] = show x ++ show treeB ++ show treeJ
```

Also,

```
show Leaf
```

is not defined:

```
show Leaf = "Leaf"
```

Comment: I somehow missed the `show Leaf` bit when I read he code. I suspect you've covered all of the issues now.